# quiero mostrar uno a uno los elementos de un array las veces que quiera con un boton

Tags: javascript

```
let eldiv=document.getElementById('div');`
let equipos = ['barcelona', 'madrid','liverpool'];`
let boton = document.getElementById('boton1');

boton.addEventListener('click',mostrar);
let index = 0;
function mostrar(){
```

el codigo que tengo me muestra los elementos del array uno a uno hasta el ultimo
al momento de presionar el boton, LO QUE QUIERO es volver a mostrar los elementos
al presionar el boton que los muestre desde el inicio

```
if(index < equipos.length){
  const  li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = equipos[index];
  eldiv.appendChild(li);
  index++;
}
```

Comment: Te he ayudado a dar formato a tu código, pero me temo que este está incompleto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), este método te dice dónde está determinado elemento empezando a contar desde un índice de 0, comprobando si el índice es el `length - 1` del array, resetearemos el `<li>`

```js
const equipos = ['barcelona', 'madrid','liverpool'];
document.querySelector("#show_btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (equipos.indexOf(showElement.textContent) === -1 || equipos.indexOf(showElement.textContent) === equipos.length - 1) {
    showElement.textContent = equipos[0];
  } else {
    showElement.textContent = equipos[equipos.indexOf(showElement.textContent) + 1];
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="eldiv">
  <button id="show_btn">Show</button>
  <p id="showElement"></p>
<div>
```

Comment: anythingg, ya lo habia recorrido en un foreach, for, pero me muestra todos lo elementos de una vez, y como esta en mi codigo quiero mostrar uno a la vez y que lo pueda volver a mostrar

Comment: @JuanPabloPeraltaCasanova He modificado mi respuesta ¿es eso lo que buscabas?

Comment: Buena respuesta, solo cambiaría la etiqueta [`<li>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) por otra, porque no forma parte de una lista.

Comment: Hecho @Triby; gracias por los comentarios

Comment: no, ese codigo recorre y muestra todos los elementos del array a la ves, yo quiero que los muestre de a uno

Comment: @JuanPabloPeraltaCasanova, acabo de probarlo y funciona como lo pediste, mostrando los equipos uno a uno.

Comment: si, funciona,muchas gracias

Comment: Y que tal si usamos el .find??

Comment: @JackNavaRow, en todo caso, [.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) parece más apropiado.